How to put a button in the title bar of a MAUI Windows app
I want to place a refresh button on my MAUI Windows app in the title bar next to the flyout menu icon.
Here is a Screenshot of what I want to do:

As a workaround, I placed it in the Shell.TitleView:
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <ImageButton Grid.Column="0" Source="refresh.png"  Clicked="RefreshButton_Clicked" />
        <controls:MyTitleControl Grid.Column="1" Title="MyTitle"/>
    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>

I need as much space as I can get for my page title, so I need to move the refresh button up to the title bar.
Please tell me how to put a button up there into the app's title bar.

Currently the TitleBar on WinUI isn't easily changeable from the xplat code. You can modify the WinUI AppTitleBar through resources #5811 but ideally you could configure it through xplat code.

You can customise your windows title bar with your own controls and layouts using following documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar#full-customization.
There is a AppWindowTitleBar which you provides the default interface and you can edit it to your liking.
